# Add text from left

Tags: android, text

I have textView with 10 lines. TextView width is choosen in the way that next notification goes to next line.
Problem is that I need that newest notification will be on highest position.
So theoretically text should be added from left.
For example if first notification is "up" and second (newest) is "down" then I wan't them listed in the way:

down

up

...

Is there easy way to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Html.fromHtml()` for example

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text1 + "<br>" + text2));
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly! Newest notification also maintains color.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show text on next line use end of line character *'\n'*
use

```
textView.setText(newMessage+"\n"+textView.getText());
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I forgot to mention that notifications are in different color. This way notifications get the same color.